# Vaadin - how to set max size for a dynamically growing panel?

Tags: size, panel, max, vaadin

The problem is the folowing:
I have to create a panel in Vaadin that has undefined heigth, but there is also a constraint that it should expand only til it reaches a maximum size (heigth).
Does anyone know a solution for this?
It is not yet implemented yet as a built-in feature in Vaadin, see:

http://dev.vaadin.com/ticket/6137

What can be done instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only approach I can think of that may be worth trying - and I've no idea if it'll work - is to try and use a containing [CSSLayout](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/layout.csslayout.html), and use max-height: in the CSS to create a maximum size for the panel.

Comment: unfortunately thats not an option because i'm using a framework that allows only horizontal and vertical layouts...

Comment: If you're restricted to Horizontal & Vertical layouts, then I'm afraid you're plain-out-of-luck - that requirement cannot be fulfilled using Vertical/Horizontal layouts in Vaadin, until that feature is developed. Kind of a crazy restriction that you can only use those layouts, though...

Comment: haha i totally forgot about this post, sorry about that:) using css did the trick so thanks again !